# How can I query the Activiti rest API for tasks with a createTime filter?

Tags: activiti

I query activiti-rest using taskVariables in the request like this: `{name=foo, type=string, value=bar, operation=equals}`. I can also filter with assignee etc. How can I limit the results to a certain time? I would need three kinds of queries:

1. Tasks before a certain date: **createTime < 1.1.2017**
2. Tasks after a certain date: **createTime > 1.1.2017**
3. Tasks between certain dates: **1.1.2015 < createTime < 1.1.2017**

I need these for both runtime and historic tasks. I could add a new *myCreateTime* taskVariable, but I don't know how to do that retroactively for existing tasks and it seems stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAve you tried using the Task history query:

https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#restHistoricTaskInstancesGet

Add the taskCreatedOn, taskCreatedBefore and taskCreatedAfter filters?

Greg